# ExportAsFixedFormat VBA Error, unsure as to why

Tags: excel, vba

Having issues getting an export to pdf to work, for some reason it isn't working and I am unsure as to why? All I want is the document to save the activeSheet to C:\Users\Documents, using the value found is cell N6.

Easy Enough...

Or so I thought...

Code:

```
Sub SaveActiveWorkbookAsPDF()

' Strings Variable
Dim fName As String
Dim saveLocation As String

' The Variables
fName = Range("N6").Value
saveLocation = "C:\Users\Documents\SDS QUOTATIONS\" & fName & "\"

' Save as PDF
.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
        "saveLocation"
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=False

End Sub
```

Any thoughts?

Thank you for your time and help,
  TCS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to remove the quotes from `saveLocation`...

```
Filename:=saveLocation
```

Also, it looks like you've omitted the username from your path, and you've mistakenly added a backslash (\) at the end of the string being assigned to `saveLocation`.  It should be something like this...

```
saveLocation = "C:\Users\<yourusername>\Documents\SDS QUOTATIONS\" & fName
```

You can also use the Environ function to get the user's name...

```
saveLocation = "C:\Users\" & Environ("username") & "\Documents\SDS QUOTATIONS\" & fName
```

Comment: Thank you, Domenic,

Multiple users will end up using this document. Is there a way to set it so it uses the user that opened it? or do I need to create multiple copies of this document?

Comment: You're very welcome.  You can use the Environ function to get the user's name.  See my edited post.